# Docusign webhooks received long after document completed

Tags: docusignapi

We are seeing webhooks hit our system with the status of Completed for documents that were completed months ago.
There is no new history listed against the document in Docusign.

Has anyone else experienced this, or know why it might be happening?

Comment: were your listener down for sometime, chances are that those messages were in failure queues. And someone pushed it manually or DS retried those messages from the failure queues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known bug in Connect. DocuSign internal bug id CONNECT-979.

As Amit mentioned in his comment, the bug can occur if a listener (your server) is not available for an extended period of time.

**It is fixed** in the March release which reached production on March 6, 2018. If the problem continues, please contact DocuSign support and reference the bug ID above.

I'm sorry that it caused a problem for you.

Comment: We had one of these webhooks come through less than 24 hours ago, although it's quite possible it was originally rejected with an error code last year. I will keep an eye on it.
Thanks for the response.